# JQuery button click event doesn't respond as expected using asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Please see my `_Layout.cshtml` code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

I check firebug net tab and saw all js file got downloaded at client pc but still jquery related no function is working.

This is first one which show alert just clicking on button which is not working

```
$(function () {
        $("#submit1").click(function () {
            alert("button");
        });

         $(".datePicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/images/calendar-icon.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select date"
         });
     });
```

when clicking on button then alert is not showing.

date picker is not coming.

where i made the mistake. please help me to sort out. am i missing any file to include? thanks

### EDIT

my view.cshtml code as follow

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.Employee


<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
</div>


<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salary)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsMale)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsMale)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JoinDate)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JoinDate, new { @class = "datePicker" })
</div>

<script>
     $(function () {
         $(".datePicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/images/calendar-icon.png",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            buttonText: "Select date"
         });
     });

</script>
```

Comment: Is that #submit1 button in the _LoginPartial page? I don't see it on your _Layout (same for .datePicker). If it is, then the JavaScript will run before your partial is loaded resulting in no actions triggering. You either need to bubble the event up to something that will be loaded, or wait until the Partial has loaded.

Comment: _LoginPartial page is in my view.cshtml

Comment: Right, but is that where your submit and datePicker "stuff" is that you're referencing? I don't see the DOM elements in the code you provided at all.

Comment: i add my view code. just see my edit

Comment: But where is the submit button and datepicker elements at? I don't see them anywhere. JavaScript won't work if there are no elements for it to select (and jQuery will not give any errors - it just won't select anything from the DOM). You need to add those items so it all wires up properly.

Comment: for the time being forget about the submit button. just tell me why date picker is not coming.

Answer (score 1):

Editor works with metadata, look at [http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-*2D00*-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx)

or change 
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JoinDate, new { @class = "datePicker" })
 to 
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JoinDate, new { @class = "datePicker" })

Comment: if i change EditorFor to TextBoxFor then it will work......why? what is wrong with EditorFor() ?

Comment: because second parameter , new { @class = "datePicker" } on the EditorFor is not for html attributes,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your View.cshtml is the page being rendered in @RenderBody, you need to reference your script in a section within your View.cshtml like this:

```
@section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/app/myscript.js")
}
```

Here's an example of the JS working (you have that correct): https://jsfiddle.net/emonrc9c/

Comment: which script i need to write in myscript.js file? i wrote my click and date picker related script in view's html file. i guess that should work.

Comment: i am new in mvc. so tell me what this `@section Scripts` does ? if possible give me article link which teach me about the usage of `@section Scripts`

Comment: @Mou No, that won't necessarily work. If you're new to MVC, I would recommend heading over to http://www.asp.net/get-started and go through some of the tutorials there as your question is now expanding in scope.